# How to send data from local PC to Google-app-engine application?

Tags: c#, java, google-app-engine

I have to write client program in C# that have to take some data from DB and sent it to my Google application(Java). How can I do that? What is the best way to do that?

It'll be great if there be some code example in answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data in JSON format and send it with server request, but I`m not sure does JAVA support working with JSON.

Comment: Java does not support it natively look here to get it to work.
http://www.json.org/java/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web service in your app engine app that would take post data and consume it.

Preferably Use a web service framework otherwise you will have to do a lot of xml parsin yourself, which is baaed. mmmkay

Now I dont know if ur using py or java, but do look for a web service framework in ur language. mmkay